# How to have a python input that behaves like bash input?

Tags: python, bash

I want to get user input in a python script after the script has begun, not as a command line argument.

I tried using pythons input method, but this behaves like a standard text-box. Is there an input type in python that behaves like the bash terminal with predictive suggestions and bash syntax such as `file{1..7}`

Comment: Just read the standard input?

Comment: You can use nice editing with [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html); but parsing things like `file{1..7}`, you'd have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you'd add which operating system you are using and for what purpose you want the 'bash-like' input. The most common way I guess would be to implement a CLI yourself and then calling the bash, but this may be a bit over the top depending on what you want to achieve.

For implementing a CLI I suggest to have a look at the [click-package](https://palletsprojects.com/p/click/). Just a quick example:

```
import click
import click_repl
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL
import os
from prompt_toolkit.history import FileHistory

@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        ctx.invoke(repl)

@cli.command()
@click.option("--directory", "-d", prompt=True, help="Directory to cd into")
def cd(directory):
    command = "cd {0}".format(directory)
    Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=None)

@cli.command()
def repl():
prompt_kwargs = {
    'history': FileHistory(os.path.expanduser('~/.repl_history'))
}
click_repl.repl(click.get_current_context(), prompt_kwargs)

try:
    cli(obj={})
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

It is important to catch a SystemExit because click always throw one after executing a command. And you have to implement every bash command you want to allow as a click command.